# Venn Diagram for the maximum of the two numbers which is greater than four.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Two dies are tossed and the outcome is the maximum of the two numbers which is greater than four.

The following doesn't make any sense to me as it doesn't explain the scenario  clearly:

[image]

The following makes sense to me, but doesn't look very efficient:

[image]

How can I draw a Venn Diagram to represent the above random experiment?

Comment: Should I just explain the first one to you? Because it seems like the most efficient one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection of the two circles, otherwise known as the union, is the number any of the die need to win. It is represented as the union because only one of the 2 die have to get a 5 or a 6 to win. It is like throwing 2 darts at the Venn Diagram, each within one of the circles, and if at least one of the darts hits the union (dark blue), you win.

Answer (score 1):

You need to visualize the **union**, not the intersection when dealing with this experiment.

[image: Venn diagram of union]

From this diagram it is easy to compute the total number of combinations giving the required outcome (greater than four): $2 \times 4 + 2 \times 2 + 4 \times 2 = 20$.

Comment: @yahoo.com When imagining the event "number on the first die is greater than four" as the left circle and the event "number on the second die is greater than four" as the right circle, the event "maximum of the two numbers is greater than four" is the union of these circles.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a conventional Venn diagram in the sense that there is no 1-1  correspondence between an element of the bubbles and an outcome.
 But it is still a relevant graphical representation of the different situations: the two colours represent the two dice, and either both dice give our a number larger than $5 $, which corresponds to the zone in the middle (both colours larger thafn $5 $) or one die gives a number less than $5 $, but in this case the other can't be also less than $5 $. This is depicted by the fact that there is no intersection between the zone where Blue $<5 $ and the zone purple $<5 $.

Edit: a clearer way would be to write "First die greater than $5 $" in the first bubble and similarly "second..." in the other one, and the intersection would naturally be the case when both dice give out numbers larger than $5 $.

Comment: @yahoo.com (funny to @ you!) I see, you are not looking for an explanation for the diagrams but for a better way to represent things. I'm going to edit  the answer.

Comment: @yahoo.com is the edit clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another look at it:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

Key: $(1,*)\cap (*,5)=(1,5)$.